# ошибка UseMethod при создании облака слов (R)

Tags: r, nlp

У меня есть 829 txt файла с экономическими новостными сводками, каждый назван по дате выхода новости, например 2014.05.16. Создаю из документов корпус,пытаюсь строить облако слов, но получаю ошибку: **"Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character""**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

```
    # Create df with texts
    files <- dir()

    df_texts <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = length(files)))
    colnames(df_texts) <- "contents"
    #colnames(df_texts) <- c("name","contents")
    #df_texts$name <- files

    # Read files to df
    df_texts$contents <- unlist(lapply(files, function(x) read_file(x, 
    locale = locale(encoding = "CP1251"))))


    # Get corpus
    txts<-Corpus(DataframeSource(df_texts), 
    readerControl=list(language="ru"))
    inspect(txts[1])
    txts<-tm_map(txts, tolower)
    txts<-tm_map(txts, removeWords, stopwords("ru"))
    txts<-tm_map(txts, removePunctuation)
    txts<-tm_map(txts, removeNumbers)
    txts<-tm_map(txts, stripWhitespace)
    txts<-tm_map(txts, removeWords, c("что", "мочь","составлять", "индекс", 
    "(анга)", "торги"))
    #plot wordcloud
    library(wordcloud)
    col=brewer.pal(6, "Dark2")
    wordcloud(txts, min.freq = 10, scale=c(9,4), rot.per = 0.5,random.color 
    = 1, max.words = 45, random.order = F, colors = col)
```

Comment: На StackOverflow был такой ответ - используйте `content_transformer`: `txts<-tm_map(txts, content_transformer(tolower))`. Возможно, и в некоторых других местах следует к нему прибегнуть.

Comment: Спасибо,это помогло!

Comment: Виктория, пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `content_transformer` с функцией `tolower`:

```
txts<-tm_map(txts, content_transformer(tolower))
```

См. [аналогичный ответ на английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771621/3832970).

Начиная с версии `tm` (0.60) невозможно использовать функции с `tm_map`, которые работают с простыми символьными значениями. Проблема с использованием tolower заключается в том, что это не "каноническая" трансформация (см. `getTransformations()`).

Функция `content_transformer` конвертирует всё в необходимый тип данных внутри корпуса. Можно использовать `content_transformer` с любой функцией, предназначенной для манипулирования символьными векторами для правильной работы в конвейерной обработке `tm_map`.
Эта функция